# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined but I can see it in the console

Tags: reactjs, json, ruby-on-rails, rest, axios

```
function RequestDetail({match}) {
  const [request, setRequests] = useState({});
  const [data, setData]= useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRequest();
}, []);
const fetchRequest = () => {
  axios
    .get(
      `${baseUrl}/${match.params.id}`
    )
    .then((res) => {
      setRequests(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

```
                   <Card key={request.id}>
                            <Card.Header>{request.user.email}</Card.Header>
                            <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title>{request.address}</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Text>
                               {request.description}<br/>
                               {request.kind}
                            </Card.Text>
                            </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
```

`

in the console I have this
[image]

any suggestions?

I just want to map the user included in the json, I have tried `.map()` but it throughs .map() is not a function

Comment: Can you post the code of your map functions? Btw looks like the result that comes form your API is an object and not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you initialize your `reuest` as an empty object in your state, until you fetch the data, your `request.user` is undefined, so it cannot read the `email` property.

Some workarounds can be

1. `<Card.Header>{request.user?.email}</Card.Header>`
2. `const [request, setRequests] = useState({ user: {} });`

Comment: thank you it worked, and if I have another nested array, how to add it to useState ?

Comment: @timjini dont forget to accept answer (green tick) :). Maybe with the nested array you should use conditional rendering inside your jsx.

Comment: I tired to find what you mentioned, but couldn't find the right way of doing it. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: can you post a new question or edit this one with the new info?

Comment: I added the code here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74310308/how-to-map-multiple-nested-arrays-json-react-rails-api

Answer (score 1):

It shows the error since the object is initially empty and you are trying to access request.user.email when request = {}.

You can try optional chaining - replace request.user.email with request?.user?.email

Another option is to initialize request with undefined so that you can use conditional rendering.

```
const [request, setRequest] = useState();
// do this when rendering
{request && 
  <Card key={request.id}>
    <Card.Header>{request.user.email}</Card.Header>
    <Card.Body>
      <Card.Title>{request.address}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>
        {request.description}<br/>
        {request.kind}
      </Card.Text>
    </Card.Body>
  </Card>
}
```