# how to map multiple nested arrays json react rails api

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple nested arrays, how can I map them ? I could map only one nested with the help of @Apostolos

`

```
function RequestDetail({match}) {
  const [request, setRequests] = useState({ user: {} });
  const [fulfillment, setFulfillments] = useState({});
  const [text, setText] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRequest();
}, []);
const fetchRequest = () => {
  axios
    .get(
      `${baseUrl}/${match.params.id}`
    )
    .then((res) => {
      setRequests(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};


const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  //e.preventDefault();
  const newfulfillment = {text}
  try{
      const response = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/${match.params.id}/fulfillments`, newfulfillment);
      setAuthHeaders();
      const allFullfilments = [...fulfillment, response.data];
      setFulfillments(allFullfilments);
      setText('');
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
  }
}
```

`

The array I need is fulfillments [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your response is an array which contains another array `fullfilments` and you
u want an array with all fullfilments right?
To do so, you need to `map` your response, and retrieve your `fullfilments`, you'll have an "array of array" which you can `.flat()`

Something like

```js
response.data.map(({fullfilments}) => fullfilments).flat()
```

Comment: So I should add this as a second .map or separately in a component?

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using rails API, with the help of Serializers I could I get the needed data in a different way.